# Are local browser extension assets served from cache on first access?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, browser-cache

### tl;dr:

I'm wondering if there's a benefit to prefetching certain images bundled with my browser extension, or if they will always be served from cache—even on first request?

### Context

In my extension, I have a few images listed at the [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources) key of my manifest.json file.  Occasionally, one of these images *seems* to take a long time to load (or to have failed entirely).

I was going to implement a kind of prefetching for the problem image, but when I inspect the image requests in the Network tab of Chrome Dev Tools, I see that these images always come `(from disk cache)` or `(from memory cache)`—even after I uninstall/reinstall the extension and clear browser cache.

This makes me believe that the offending image will not be affected by prefetching, as it is already coming from the cache.  I'd like to rule prefetching out as a solution before considering more exotic options.

Comment: The extensions aren't really served as there's no built-in server in the browser. The files are read directly from the disk just like any other cached files. As for "from memory" I guess it's caused by the internal implementation of resource fetcher that doesn't know anything about extensions in particular so it tries to cache the files even though it should not be normally needed. The pause you're seeing may be caused by something else (like a limit on concurrent requests in a tab), including a bug in the browser. You can probably read the image, convert into a data URI and set it directly.

Comment: Thanks for the fast and thorough reply.  I've noticed that some [CSP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) settings, including `img-src *` will reject data URI images, so I'm reluctant to go that route. I was wondering about concurrent requests though, so I'll definitely investigate that.